# How to make Visual Studio read my custom wizard (IDTWizard) dll?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dllimport, wizard, dllregistration

I have a custom wizard to help me generate code. The implementation currently works if i have the code generator project in the active solution.

I want to take out the project from the active solution and have Visual Studio recognize the custom code generator wizard.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this walkthrough? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k3w6w59(v=vs.110).aspx

If you get it to work properly, please let me know. I'm having problems with mine:
[Error "Invalid at the top level of the document" creating a Visual Studio 2012 Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188932/creating-a-visual-studio-2012-wizard)