# Error "Invalid at the top level of the document" creating a Visual Studio 2012 Wizard

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, wizard

I am trying to create a New Item Wizard for Visual Studio 2012. This would be a wizard to create several C++ files and add them to the project. I have created a similar wizard for VS 2005. I'm trying to create this using the IDTWizard interface. I followed this walkthrough: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k3w6w59(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k3w6w59%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

When i try to use the wizard, I get an error message that says "invalid at the top level of the document". My dll shows up as a registered COM object when I look through the data displayed by oleview.exe. What am I doing wrong? Should I be doign this the same way I created my VS2005 wizard, using html/javascript? My code is below:

Wizard.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SystemsModuleWizard
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("FE7DC545-30DC-445B-8130-897C5F3114EC"), ProgId("SystemsModuleWizard.WizardClass")]

    public class WizardClass : IDTWizard
    {
        public void Execute(object Application,
            int hwndOwner, ref object[] contextParams,
            ref object[] customParams,
            ref EnvDTE.wizardResult retval) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The wizard is running");

        }
    }
}
```

AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("SystemsModuleWizard")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("SystemsModuleWizard")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2014")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible 
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from 
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]

// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[assembly: Guid("ab29b7df-32c4-4dca-ade4-a31f687b9331")]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Comment: It is an error message that's produced by an XML parser.  Far removed from your code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

I notice your `Execute` implementation is:

```
public void Execute(object Application,
        int hwndOwner, ref object[] contextParams,
        ref object[] customParams,
        ref EnvDTE.wizardResult retval) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The wizard is running");

    }
```

But according to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.idtwizard.execute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `retval` is an `out` parameter, not a `ref` parameter:

```
void Execute(
    Object Application,
    int hwndOwner,
    ref Object[] ContextParams,
    ref Object[] CustomParams,
    out wizardResult retval
)
```

The walkthrough you linked to certainly gives it as `ref`, but perhaps that's an error. I don't see how both can work--the memory allocation and marshalling would be different. Give it a try. Hope this helps.

Comment: No, that only matters to the C# compiler, its *definite assignment checking* feature depends on it.  It is irrelevant to COM.

Answer (score 0):

I was intrigued by this, so I knocked up a quick wizard following the steps in your linked walkthrough. But it worked fine:

[image]

(And it turns out the question of `ref` or `out` param doesn't arise, as it won't even compile with `out`. So [that other MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.idtwizard.execute(v=vs.110).aspx) is plain wrong to give it as `out`.)

So I set out to see how I could break it.

Here's how: introduce an error into the `.vsz` file, . For example, if your file contains the lines

```
VSWIZARD 7.0
Wizard=MyNewWizard.Class1
Param=First Item
Param=Second Item
```

mis-spell the classname in the second line:

```
Wizard=ThyNewWizard.Class1
```

When I did this, it obligingly displayed your error message:

[image]

Since you've checked that your class is registered with COM, it therefore looks likely to be a typo etc in your `.vsz` file.